Wordpress on VULTR - Syncing to another Server
We have a server hosted on VULTR through Cloudways.
We just experienced a 15 hour shut down by VULTR (server is back up now) but this has led to my looking into how I can have a backup server that is 100% in sync at all times.
I am just looking to have a perfect backup at all times, that I can repoint my DNS in case this happens again.
Any suggestions?

Pointing a DNS entry to a different IP usually takes up to 48 hours to propagate. That won't help you much.

This is possible if you run a load balancer. Nginx load balancer offers this kind of feature. What you would need is to have at least 3 VPS servers: one acts as a load balancer and the others could act as the edge nodes.

Load balancer can direct traffic, but it won't sync your application.
